# Add a field in ElasticSearch using python with boolean datatype?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-dsl-py

How do add a new field of a particular datatype(boolean) in Elasticsearch using python.
Is this query correct?

```
es.update(index='my_index', doc_type='my_doctype', id='id_of_doc', body={"doc": {"new_field":"boolean_value"},"type":"boolean"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an API supported by elasticsearch. To create a boolean field use the `put_mapping` API (0) or just send a `boolean` value (`True` or `False`) from python and elasticsearch will create the field for you automatically (1).

0 - https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_mapping

1 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/dynamic-mapping.html